# Dynamically Check Page Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Trying to auto-sign up on https://www.paletasmorelia.com/join-rewards/
Using code right now for clicking things i

```
def type(class_name, text):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name))
        )
        if element:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", element, text)
            print(f"Typed '{text}' in the element found by class name!")
        else:
            print("Element not found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred: {e}")
```

However, when the page first loads, it uses a popup, and it blocks everything, and doesnt allow selenium to find the fields for some reason, even after clicking off popup. Any ideas?

Tried searching by classname, xpath, etc. Nothing helped.